# Oracle Sequence getting updated by cache size+lastnumber

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

The Sequence in oracle db is getting updated by cache size+lastnumber value, when app server(tomcat) gets restart. My application is using Hibernate jpa along with this connection pool is getting created in appserver.

Example. Suppose select  xxx.nextval  from dual is giving 1,2 ,3.... so on as gets fired. Cache size is 100 and LAST_NUMBER is 101.
Now if restart the app server ie tomcat then select  xxx.nextval will start giving 101 and LAST_NUMBER  will become 201.

Comment: Set cache size to 1 if you want to reduce unused sequence numbers.

Comment: Do some basic research yourself and you will see that this is expected behaviour for an Oracle sequence. It isn't a problem unless you need gap-less consecutive numbers - in which case a sequence is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather say that this is what happens: presume that cache size is 20. The last sequence fetch *fetched* the `NEXTVAL`, but cached 20 values which weren't used. If they aren't used for a while, they get out of the shared pool and are *lost*. You don't need to restart the database or your application server; it just *happens*.

In my opinion, you shouldn't worry about it. Sequences aren't designed to provide gap-free sequence of numbers, but its values will always be unique, will be retrieved very fast, can be used in a multi-user environment, ... - so, everything's OK.